# How to achieve NUMBER(Oralce) data type functionality in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes

I am having a oracle table column values like 4.138
153.2809
128.113141081389 trying to load these values into snowflake with the table DDL NUMBER(38,16). So the values are now in snowflake table becomes 4.1380000000000000
153.2809000000000000
128.1131410813890000 but i need to load the values as such in oracle to snowflake with out trailing 0.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that's a storage problem not just a display problem? You can probably format them as you display them.

Comment: You mean to say it is display problem. Do you have any tutorials to format in column level to display to the user?

Comment: It is a storage issue. i tried to extract data from snowflake and it is having trailing 0 in it.4.1380000000000000153.2809000000000000

Comment: Extract them how? I don't know Snowflake but [the formatting docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#fixed-position-numeric-formats) say "Normally, the leading zeros in the integer part and trailing zeros in the fractional part are replaced with spaces" so this must be possible, and should be the default.

Answer (score 1):

To format a fixed-position numeric type so that it does not display trailing zeros:

```
create or replace table TEST_NUMBERS (N number(38,16));
insert into TEST_NUMBERS(N) values (4.138), (153.2809), (128.113141081389);

select to_varchar(N, 'FMTM') as COMPACT_NUMBER from TEST_NUMBERS;

-- The "FM" toggles the "Fill Mode" to compact from the default, which is full.
-- The "TM" specifies using "Text Minimal".
-- It requires both Fill Mode of compact and Text Minimal set to suppress trailing
-- zeros on fixed-position numbers.
```

This is of course only for display and output. If you want to see how scale and precision affect storage and computation, there is a note in this section of the docs:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#impact-of-precision-and-scale-on-storage-size

Answer (score 0):

well, generally if you want to store the data without the trailing zeroes you should just cut on scale. A NUMBER(38,3) will store 4.138 and nothing more than that.

and if it's for display purpose then just change the formatting string according to https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#fixed-position-numeric-formats

Comment: But my requirement is decimal digits will vary record to record ex:153.2809. So i defined NUMBER(38,16). So Snowflake NUMBER data type will not work like Oracle NUMBER data type?

Comment: It works exactly the same. Oracle also saves it with the same scale, it's only a matter of display. if you explain what exactly your usecase is we might be able to help better.

Comment: Decimal values have place-holder zeroes in the fractional portion.  You can cast to float to eliminate the zeroes.  You can cast to text to bypass formatting your tooling may be applying.  For example, `select 1.23456789::number(38,16)::float::text, 1.23456789::number(38,16)::text;`

Comment: I would not do that.... a cast to float can actually change the value due to lack of precision.